# "Saying that" meaning

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

It is hard for me to understand the meaning of the expression "saying that". If it is at the beginning of the sentence, how is it right to explain? Where is it appropriate to use and what construction to write?

Here's an example, from a list of tips about how to improve English:

> 1. Plan to take a test. You’ll find that you work harder when you need to study for something.
> 2. **Saying that,** it’s better not to study just to take a test. Think of the bigger picture. What can you do when you have a good command of English? How will the quality of your life improve?

Comment: I suggest you use it and avoid the fossilized expressions to make your speech and writing more vibrant and concise and maintaining the emphasis of the present tense.

Answer (score 1):

I believe "saying that" is used in the same sense of "having said that", "that said" or "that being said".

However, it is not a common phrase. I suggest you avoid it and use the more common and fossilized phrases such as those which are listed above.

Comment: Agree.  The phrase “having said that” is an example of a **cliché** — avoid!

Answer (score 0):

*Having said that, X*, *Saying that, X*, *That being said, X*, *There again, X* and a number of other similar expressions mean:

- Something was previously said that was a good idea, helpful thing, or general rule.

  - It can be a previous sentence you said or a previous sentence someone else said.
- X is an exception to that idea, thing, or rule.
- X doesn't make the good idea, thing, or rule wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In the question "Who does that help, saying that?" the phrase "saying that" serves to specify what action or statement is being referred to. It is used to clarify the context and focus of the inquiry.

Here's a breakdown of the question:

"Who" is asking about the people or individuals involved or affected.
"does that help" is inquiring about the beneficial or detrimental effects of the action or statement.
"saying that" specifies the action or statement in question.
So, "saying that" is an essential part of the question because it directs the query toward the specific words or actions being discussed and their potential impact or benefit to certain individuals or groups.

Comment: Where did you get that sentence? Your use of "saying that" and the OP's use of it are not the same.